# How to intercept database operation in EF core 3?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

How do I intercept before the database operation like select/delete/insert/update using EF core 3 in PostgreSQL?

In the new feature of EF core 3.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/#interception-of-database-operations, `DbCommandInterceptor` is used for that. However, I couldn't find this class nor the `AddInterceptors`.

Do I need to install new nuget or using specific namespace?

Comment: Add `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --version 3.0.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found what I need and successfully implemented.

```
using System.Data.Common;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

public class RowLevelSecurityInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
  public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
    DbCommand command,
    CommandEventData eventData,
    InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
  {
    // command.CommandText += " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)";
    return result;
  }
}
```

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  // previous codes
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {

    optionsBuilder
      .UseNpgsql(GetConnectionString())
      .AddInterceptors(new RowLevelSecurityInterceptor());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with your sample code. Any hint? 
`'InterceptionResult.Result' was called when 'InterceptionResult.HasResult' is false.`

Comment: This works fine for me, for EF Core queries that *read* data, but none of the other overridable functions seem to cater for data being written back to the database.  Has anyone else noticed this ?